# After a calendar image is selected, the cursor is moving to first place

Tags: asp.net

I put two text fields in a grid. One is a calender and outside the text field I put the calender button. Here is the problem:

Grid lines contains 600 rows. If I select, for example, the 200th or 300th row after selecting the calendar image, it is moving to the upside ...which means the cursor position is moving to first 1 to 50 rows. How can I fix it? So, if I select the image at 100 200 it is moving to upside again come to down side and then select the date.

This is my code at image button click:

```
Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs)
    Dim Cnt, Rowcnt As Integer
    Rowcnt = Gridview1.Rows.Count
    Dim rowindex As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Gridview1.SelectedRow)
    Dim gvr As GridViewRow = Gridview1.Rows(rowindex)
    Dim btnEdit As ImageButton = TryCast(sender, ImageButton)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(btnEdit.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    Dim introwindex As Integer
    introwindex = row.RowIndex

    For Cnt = 0 To Rowcnt
        If (Cnt = introwindex) Then
            cal1 = DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(Cnt).FindControl(("Calendar1")), Calendar)
            cal1.Visible = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using webforms, take a look at [MaintainScroolPositionOnPostback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx) property. This might help you.